# Kusto: Filter results to latest record for each ID

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Suppose I have a table like the following in [Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/):

```
let data = datatable(id:int, dateTime:datetime)
[
    1,"2021-03-03",
    1,"2021-03-04",
    1,"2021-03-12",
    2,"2021-03-04",
    2,"2021-03-04",
    2,"2021-03-07"
]
```

I want a [Kusto Query Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/) query that will find the record with the latest datetime for each id. I.e., I want the query to return the following records:

| id | dateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1 | 2021-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 |

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66495039/kusto-query-to-get-the-latest-column-value-which-is-not-empty-for-each-column) but in this case the OP wanted only one record, which was the max for the entire table. I want to get back the record with the latest datetime for *each* id.

How can I do this?

---

<sub>(This sample table is for illustrative purposes, the real data I am dealing with is much larger and has many IDs, and is unsorted.)</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> *I want a Kusto Query Language query that will find the record with the latest datetime for each id*

If you wish to only get the maximum datetime value for each id, you should use the `max()` aggregation function:

```
datatable(id:int, dateTime:datetime, message:string)
[
    1,"2021-03-03", "a",
    1,"2021-03-04", "b",
    1,"2021-03-12", "c",
    2,"2021-03-04", "d",
    2,"2021-03-04", "e",
    2,"2021-03-07", "f"
]
| summarize max(dateTime) by id
```

| id | max_dateTime |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 1 | 2021-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 |

Or, if you wish to preserve other columns of the maximized record, you should use the `arg_max()` aggregation function:

```
datatable(id:int, dateTime:datetime, message:string)
[
    1,"2021-03-03", "a",
    1,"2021-03-04", "b",
    1,"2021-03-12", "c",
    2,"2021-03-04", "d",
    2,"2021-03-04", "e",
    2,"2021-03-07", "f"
]
| summarize arg_max(dateTime, *) by id
```

| id | dateTime | message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2021-03-07 00:00:00.0000000 | f |
| 1 | 2021-03-12 00:00:00.0000000 | c |